# flutter run hangs on adb command

Tags: android, flutter, adb, freeze

I have these emulators in Flutter on linux:

```
$ flutter emulators
2 available emulators:

Nexus_5X_API_29_x86 • Nexus 5X API 29 x86 • Google • android
flutter_emulator    • flutter emulator    • Google • android

To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.

You can find more information on managing emulators at the links below:
  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager
```

I'm trying to run my code in the `flutter_emulator`, but it just hangs on an `adb` command.

When I run `flutter run -v`, it hangs.

```
[  +32 ms] executing: [/home/skuzzymiglet/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +42 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[        ] executing: [/home/skuzzymiglet/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +7 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[  +10 ms] executing: [/home/skuzzymiglet/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/skuzzymiglet/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +12 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +72 ms] executing: [/home/skuzzymiglet/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +173 ms] executing: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +11 ms] Exit code 0 from: /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86
           transport_id:1
[  +27 ms] /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
(hangs)
```

From `strace`, it just stops.

Comment: Did you solve that?

Comment: @FernandoSantos No. [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40443) might help though

Comment: "killall adb" works for me on ubuntu 20.04